# Perturbing x,y components in order to plot a graph?

Tags: matlab

Sorry if this question seems odd. I have to use MATLAB for a project in class, and I have very little programming background. I'm trying to randomly perturb points in a graph so that I get a cleaner. My current graph looks like this:
[image]

I'm using the following code:

```
figure; hold on;

plot(XTest(yTest==1, 1), XTest(yTest==1, 2), '+');
plot(XTest(yTest==0, 1), XTest(yTest==0, 2), 'o');

slope = -w(1)/w(2);
intercept = gamm/ w(2);
refline(slope, intercept);
xlabel(sprintf('Feature %i', bestFeatures(1)));
ylabel(sprintf('Feature %i', bestFeatures(2)));
legend('Malignant test examples', 'Benign test examples');
title('Test set classification results');
```

XTest is a 28x30 matrix of values generated from a self-defined function, and YTest is a 28x1 matrix of either 1s or 0s.

I'd like to perturb each x and y component by a random variable drawn from a uniform distribution on [-.05, .05], but I have no idea how to do this. Help would be much appreciated!

Edit: I tried the following code:

```
% + plots
x1 =  (rand*0.1-0.05) * XTest(yTest==1, 1);
y1 = (rand*0.1-0.05) * XTest(yTest==1, 2);

% o plots
x2 = (rand*0.1-0.05) * XTest(yTest==0, 1);
y2 = (rand*0.1-0.05) * XTest(yTest==0, 2);


plot(x1, y1, '+');
plot(x2, y2, 'o');
slope = -w(1)/w(2);
intercept = gamm/ w(2);
refline(slope, intercept);
xlabel(sprintf('Feature %i', bestFeatures(1)));
ylabel(sprintf('Feature %i', bestFeatures(2)));
legend('Malignant test examples', 'Benign test examples');
title('Test set classification results');
```

But my graph ended up looking like:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty? [rand](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) gives a random number in [0,1] range, so `rand*0.1-0.05` will return one in [-0.05,0.05] range.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for replying again, Anthony! I edited my post to show my attempt

Comment: Ha didn't realise it is you. So is there a problem with your implementation of perturbing algorithm? Sorry, I'm not familiar with that. You could wait for others who know the algorithm to help you or describe it so that general people like me can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you not need to add the random perturbation instead of multiplying it?